# Is there a way to list AWS Iam user properties

Tags: aws-cli

I can't find a way to list IAM users with the following info:

- Username
- Key age
- Password age
- Last login
- MFA Enabled
- last use
- key Active?

I have tried `aws iam list-users` but that doesn't tell me much.

Is this possible using the AWS CLI? If so, how?

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: To the four people who voted to close this, as someone who actually writes code using the AWS CLI, I can vouch that this is an excellent question that needs an answer and doesn't belong in Server Fault, which is for sysadmin questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will put in an answer, since 4 people have voted, unfairly I think, to close the question.

The short answer is, no, there's no one command you can use to do this, and I can understand why that's confusing and surprising.

Some of this info can be found in the credential report using:

```
aws iam generate-credential-report
aws iam get-credential-report
```

See the docs for how to programmatically obtain the credentials report ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html)).

From there you can get:

- mfa_active
- access_key_1_active
- access_key_1_last_used_date
- access_key_1_last_rotated
- password_last_used
- password_last_changed

Some other info can be found in the `list-access-keys` subcommand:

```
▶ aws iam list-access-keys --user-name alex 
{
    "AccessKeyMetadata": [
        {
            "UserName": "alex", 
            "Status": "Active", 
            "CreateDate": "XXXX-XX-XXT01:33:31Z", 
            "AccessKeyId": "XXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thus, you can get the "Status" and "CreateDate" from here too using commands like:

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name alex \
  --query "AccessKeyMetadata[].CreateDate" \
  --output text
```

More info again can be found in:

```
▶ aws iam get-login-profile --user-name alex   
{
    "LoginProfile": {
        "UserName": "alex", 
        "CreateDate": "XXXX-XX-XXT01:33:31Z", 
        "PasswordResetRequired": false
    }
}
```

You can also get the access key last used date this way:

```
access_key_id=$(aws iam list-access-keys \
  --user-name alex \
  --query "AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId" \
  --output text)

aws iam get-access-key-last-used \
  --access-key-id $access_key_id
```

For example of output:

```
{
    "UserName": "alex", 
    "AccessKeyLastUsed": {
        "Region": "XXXXXX", 
        "ServiceName": "iam", 
        "LastUsedDate": "XXXX-XX-XXT05:28:00Z"
    }
}
```

I think that covers all the fields you asked about. Obviously, you would need to write a bit of code around all this to get it all together.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I appreciate the solidarity 

Comment: I intended to write a small bash script

Comment: It would be surprising to me if you weren't intending to write some bash code, considering that the question is about the AWS CLI.